I have been trying to interpret some slang Italian, can you help?
I am looking to interpret two slang words my Zia used a lot. The first one sounded like "Deebahgahdah". At least to me it sounds like that. The second one sounds like " Cugahfreesula" U as in umbrella... Please help if possible. I believe she was also from the MonteCassino area. This is how it sounded to me

Can you give us more context about how these words are used? It's hard to interpret phonetic transcriptions made by a non-native. Moreover it's likely that these are not standard Italian, thus increasing the difficulty

Hi, thanks for responding. I believe they were directed at older men, men in possibly their 70s and 80s I got the impression it was something like "dirty old man" or "old buck" Zia didn't like men

For some more context, my sister thinks it was pointed at men that older women might date as  in " Why would she date that old Cugahfreedsula"? " He is "Deebahgahdah"
